# Perché usiamo "dillo" e non "dilla" al posto di "della festa" in una frase con l'imperativo

Tags: grammar, pronouns

La risposta alla domanda

> "A chi altro devo dire della festa?"

può essere

> "Dillo anche ai tuoi colleghi".

Come mai usiamo "**dillo**" e non "**dilla**" dato che il pronome sostituisce "**della festa**" che è femminile?

Qualcuno me lo potrebbe spiegare? Come funziona?

Comment: Qualcun altro lo spiegherà meglio, ma il “lo” di “dillo” non c'entra con “la festa”, perché “dire” non è usato in modo transitivo. Se così fosse, “dilla” sarebbe effettivamente la forma giusta (“A chi altro devo dire la notizia?” “Dilla a chi ti pare”).

Comment: @DaG:   Ho l'impressione che il verbo *dire* in  *dillo* sia transitivo, ma che si usi il pronome *lo* con valore neutro, in modo simile a questa sostituzione: "Dicevo che ci sarebbe una festa" --> "Lo dicevo".

Comment: Se fosse intransitivo, come, per esempio, "parlare", si userebbe la particella "ne": "A chi altro devo parlare della festa?" "Parlane anche ai tuoi colleghi".

Comment: Hai perfettamente ragione, @Charo, mi sono espresso male: è transitivo anche nella frase della domanda, ma il complemento oggetto non è la festa.

Comment: - D: _A chi devo dire **della festa**?_ -> "della festa" è complemento di
   argomento, non complemento oggetto
 - R: _Dil**lo** anche ai tuoi colleghi_ -> il pronome "lo" è complemento oggetto ma nella domanda non c'è alcun complemento oggetto a cui fare riferimento; il pronome non sostituisce "la festa" ma, più genericamente, l'argomento di cui si sta parlando. "Dil*lo* a..." = "di' _l'argomento_/_ciò_ a..."